# Find needle in a haystack?

Tags: electrical-engineering

How can we find it with the current technologies? Can it done without touching the haystack? Any cool stuffs like X-ray or some penetrating technologies ?

Comment: mythbusters did an episode on that.

Comment: Huge magnet? You didn't say it had to remain in the haystack.

Comment: Thank you bro.... a magnet should work. But next try let say I am given a carbon or fiber glass needle.

Comment: What if the needle is made of hay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say X ray is the best bet. Or possibly ultrasound, metal detector (high powered). 
Maybe since you never said the haystack has to remain intact, you could burn it down and search for the needle with a metal detector in the ashy remains.

Comment: Well let say, "Can it done without touching the haystack?" means the haystack has to remain intact. I was just wondering if Sonar can do the trick as well , since if the sound can travel the place the needle can and if we can process the details before and after dropping. I dono can it ?

Comment: Ok so putting aside destruction, good plan. I think the reason sonar wouldn't work too well is because materials like hay are very good at absorbing compressions and rarefactions in air (sound waves). If you look in a recording studio you can see the walls are made of spongy foam - this empty space is very good at dispersing the energy. So the reason sonar might not work is because the hay would act as a shield.   Unrelated yet interesting: A great example of using 'empty' space to disperse energy from a wave would be the protective concrete loops found around the (to be continued)

Comment: (Cont...) man made island built for the Burj Al Arab, a tall building in Dubai. The concrete loops act just the way the haystack would. Or the walls of a recording studio!

Comment: Thank you for the details provided much appreciated. Ruling this out of the equation we are left only with X-ray I suppose. But to be honest this thought occurred to me when I was reading about some article about space exploration science where people find what's the composition of distance planets using the concept of dispersion of different elements differently. If so hay should disperse different from the needle right? Is this application appropriate somehow ?

Comment: You're most welcome! I haven't heard of that method used in exploring outer space and exo planets. The way I know about is through analysis of light. The light reflected from a planet or emitted from a star can be broken down into its wavelengths. Every element has a different light signature. Looking at the light from the object and breaking it down into the elements allows scientists to determine what the celestial body is composed of, this of course allows us to determine if the planet can sustain life. (As long as it is in the Goldilocks zone). Sorry the subject is constantly changing!

Comment: But what you said may well be what I just said. I just wasn't sure about the usage of the word dispersion. Looking back I guess that could make sense. This method of finding the needle would however be similar to using an X-ray. You'd have an X ray emitting source on one side of the hay stack and a receiver on the other. This is like the exoplanet method. You receive signatures, however in this case you hope to receive an image with a little needle somewhere in the stack. You're not analysing what is reflected from it, but what's not coming from it... So the difference in X-ray intensity.

Comment: The needle of course would block some X-rays - minimising their intensity in that area. Bare in mind that this would give you a 2d view of wear the needle is. You'd have to repeat the process on one more axis (from above) - you now have latitudinal position and longitudinal position in relation the the hay.

Comment: Thank you. So basically people use this light signature to segregate elements.  Then let's say the needle then can be found using a detector analysing light. I agree this sound like sci-fi but I am just trying to find if it's possible given some ideal conditions using this light signature.

Comment: Yes, you use te light signature to determine an element. But no, you wouldn't use an X-ray and analyse the light reflected from the needle, but you would use it to determine where it is. This is because the needle will block out some of the X-rays, and this will appear to be darker line on the screen. Like holding the needle up to the light, you see it's silhouette. And no worries! You're enthusiastic, curious and inspired and that's great. It sounds like you're actually planning on finding a needle!

Comment: Thank you Jan. One last way I was thinking to achieve this. The fact the needle is difficult to find in a haystack is because it's so small. So let's say I make it big after dropping it by, let's say I pass or suffocate the haystack with a gas of some sort that reacts with needle and settles on top of it and also does not react with hay.  If I do this consistently then I should find it a thicker and bigger right?  But of course I have to disturb the haystack. But at least I don't have to destroy it. Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: This would be a way to do it if you didn't mind destroying your needle. Using a gas so react with the needle would probably not be worth it though, the only thing I'd know how to do (I'm not studying chemistry) would be to oxidise it. This would make the needle rust and increase the volume by a fraction. This would probably deem the needle unusable and still rather hard to find as it wouldn't have become much bigger. In fact I would say it would be harder to find by eye because it would have lost its shine. The easiest way to get the needle would be to spread the hay and use a metal detector!